# 12.04 to 14.04 upgrade hangs at "preparing to configure gdb"

Tags: upgrade

I have a Dell Inspiron i5-3542 laptop reinstalled with Ubuntu 12.05 LTS, however when I tried to upgrade to 14.04 the system hung at `preparing to configure gdb`.

How can I solve this issue?